# Avoid floating point zero when summing scaled set of numbers in R

Tags: r, floating-point, rescale

I am rescaling a set of numbers and want to avoid getting a floating point zero for the sum of the rescaled numbers:

```
x <- c(-5, 1, 8)
y <- scale(x)
sum(y)
# [1] 1.249001e-16
```

Is there a way to around this to force the sum to zero? I do not care about precision beyond a three decimal places.

Comment: Isn't this sum already precise beyond three decimal places?

Comment: @hpesoj626 the scaled vector `y` goes into a function that requires the `sum(y) == 0`. Need something to get me beyond this if statement

Comment: how about requiring `round(sum(y), 3) == 0` in your function instead?

Comment: @hpesoj626 its not my function... was trying to avoid hacking other peoples code

Comment: If the routine that `y` is passed to requires the sum of numbers calculated with floating-point arithmetic to be exactly zero, then it is not properly designed to work with floating-point arithmetic and should be fixed. Forcing the elements of y to sum to zero is not a good solution, as it will increase the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not just "switch" to integers at some point. The scaling was computed with floating point numbers and is therefore not 100% precise. Forcing some values to 0 would indicate a precision that is not available and should thus be avoided.

If you need to compare floating point values use `isTRUE(all.equal(...))` as suggested by R documentation. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html

Comment: This does not answer the question.